# How to sandbox a div element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to build a content editor. This contenteditor will load a HTML document (with JavaScript) into for example a #result element. The problem with this, is that if inside this HTML element there is for example `$("input").hide();`, then all of my inputs are gone throughout the whole page, so not just inside the loaded HTML (my goal).

What I want to do with the editor is when a client clicks on an element that represents something in the database, the info of this element will popup and the user will be able to edit this. (So, if a user hovers over a form with the class "contact-form" (which is in the database, **connected** to the loaded page) a new window will popup with information about this specific form element.

Also, I cannot completely disable Javascript, since the loaded HTML might contain Javascript for styling etc.

**My goal**: Remove Javascript, that can be annoying when a user loads in an HTML file. Like an alert(); Also, remove the ability for the Javascript to edit somehthing outside it's own DOM.

P.S. I am open to better workarounds like using an iframe for this, BUT I want to be able to hover over elements in interact with them.

**Edit:** It seems that this question might be a bit too broad, looking at the comments. **Summary of my question:** How can I disable alert() for a specific div and how can I create a sandbox so that code inside a div, can only change elements from inside that div.

Comment: Please post some code. and where exactly you are facing issue.

Comment: you dont need to sandbox this div in this case. look for sql injection, this is exactly the same as that one.. well atleast the cause. so to avoid this, use the methods used to avoid sql injection.

Comment: also, when u capture this editable content convert all special characters to their respective html entities.. google for html entities

Comment: @ravishankar I do not have any code, and I am not (really) looking for any. The thing I want, is a solution to my problem. Not the code to build the solution.

Comment: @AkshayKhandelwal This indeed has nothing to do with the server side communication. I've got that covered.

Comment: @GerritLuimstra Then Stack Overflow is the wrong place for you. It's supposed to be for code help. If you haven't tried anything yet, then the focus of your question is too broad to answer.

Comment: @Soviut that is the very way sql injection starts.. as i said already this is the flaw that dev's overlook ans thus fall prey to the hackers

Comment: @Soviut Alright. I don't think this is fair. But let me explain this. I've looked up alot on the internet and I have seen some content editors. I've seen their behavior and code, but want I want, is a simple explanation to how they do this. I don't believe StackOverflow is purely for code. It is about programming, am I right?

Comment: As long as the developer is using query parameters to escape input, SQL injection isn't possible. The issue here is the OP wants to know about HTML sanitization, however, they haven't provided enough of an attempt in their initial question.

Comment: @GerritLuimstra yes, it's for programming, but not something this broad. You need to at least make an attempt so that your focus is narrowed down enough. Break your problem down, try things, then ask several separate questions so that you can get more specific answers.

Comment: @Soviut Updated. Is this better?

Comment: @GerritLuimstra You're still asking two questions but I'll see if I can provide something since it all relates to disabling javascript.

Comment: @GerritLuimstra I will close this question. Since it is NOT about disabling Javascript if you've read my question. It is about breaking the link between the loaded "DOM" and the initial DOM. And thus "Sandbox" a div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is HTML sanitization. This is the process by which you remove any dangerous content from a snippet of HTML on the server, before it's loaded in the browser. There are plenty of sanitization libraries out there that can strip script tags, object tags, etc. Just remember, you can't sanitize using javascript because by the time you've injected your script, another malicious script may have already loaded and run.

The only way to effectively sandbox a javascript environment is with iframes. You'll notice that websites like [CodePen](http://codepen.io/), [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/) and [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) use them extensively. There's something called the ShadowDOM, which is the basis of Web Components, but it isn't very well supported yet.

To make it possible to run your own frontend scripts that allow for hovering, you can inject your script after your sanitization process. This way, if it's loaded inside an iframe your script will also be loaded.

Finally, `alert()` doesn't belong to any elements on the DOM. You can trigger an alert as soon as the page loads, for example. However, if you're trying to prevent alerts from popping up on user interactions, you could try removing all event listeners from a particular element. This won't be necessary if you sanitize the HTML of script tags, however, since the script wouldn't have had a chance to load so there won't be any event listeners.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you! This is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`ShadowDOM`](https://www.w3.org/TR/shadow-dom/) to load an `html` document into a [`host`](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-documentfragment-host) node. See also [WHY SHADOW DOM?](http://webcomponents.org/polyfills/shadow-dom/)